# Can Apache Alluxio use Azure Data Lake as under store?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, alluxio

I have created a HDInsight Cluster with Spark2.2 & HDI 3.6 that read data from Azure Data Lake.
Users will execute Spark-SQL on it, I want to use Alluxio as a cache to speed up queries. After some research, I found Azure Blob Storage is supported: http://www.alluxio.org/docs/1.7/en/Configuring-Alluxio-with-Azure-Blob-Store.html. I am wondering does Azure Data Lake also supported?

Answer (score 0):

From ADLS team, we do not have support for it, sorry.

Can you please enter this as a feature request here - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake? That will help us understand the community's demand for it as well as help us in our prioritization.

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth
Program Manager, Azure Data Lake Store